# Why does echo into the hosts file in Windows PowerShell creates spaces between characters?

Tags: windows, powershell, echo

Running the following commands in Administrator mode PowerShell on Windows 8.1 creates weird output:

```
PS C:\> cat C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
```

Above is the initial content of the hosts file.

```
PS C:\> echo "127.0.0.1 example.com" >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

I add a line using echo command and ...

```
PS C:\> cat C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 1   e x a m p l e . c o m     

PS C:\>
```

Notice the last line; it has spaces between every character that was echoed.

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the obvious solution is to not use the `echo "text" >> file` format. Try using add-content instead:

```
Add-Content -Path C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. -Value "127.0.0.1 example.com"
```

This will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is PowerShell uses Unicode by default.

This will achieve what you are trying to do:

```
ECHO "127.0.0.1 example.com" | Out-File -Append -Encoding ASCII MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In CMD, not Powershell:

```
echo ip.address hostname.domainname >> %Systemdrive%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

ie:

```
echo 127.0.0.1 microsoft.com >> %Systemdrive%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```